# Unable to open rewritten, dynamic url in python

Tags: url, dynamic, web-scraping, url-rewriting, scrapy

I am trying to open a page using python code. The code is as follows:

```
***
import urllib2

r = urllib2.urlopen("https://shop.adidas.co.in/gateway/catalog/api/product/ADIDAS_IN/
S26999/
attributevalues")
***
```

But it's giving:

> ERROR: 400 Bad request.

Opening the url works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.